# How to add a single menu item in wordpress to my plugin

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am trying to create my first wordpress plugin and I want to add a new "menu item" in the wordpress default menu bar. So when I click that menu item, the html form need to be shown by my plugin.

comparing to Joomla, in joomla it has views in "components" so I can easily create a new menu item, and assign a view as I want. In wordpress how do I do that for a plugin?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the admin menu when you are administering the website, or the pages menu that visitors see on the front end?

Comment: i actually need both, I've meant the "pages menu on the front end" in my question as I'm trying that first. But I need to add an admin menu as well in the "dashboard menu". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that for your form for the front end, make a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that will render your form. Then people can create a page (which gets you your menu item) and put your form on the page, optionally with some text / images above or below the form. This is better than trying to insert a "page" into the menu and somehow getting it where your plugin's users want it to go :)

For the admin side, use the [admin menu functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).

Comment: Hi webaware, Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Im gonna try this right now.

Comment: Hi webware, Thanks for your help! and it works!! may be you can help me on another thing, can you suggest a way that I can make the form separately and add it to the function, instead of writing it in the function. Thanks.

Comment: Put the form into a template, and load it via [load_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template). Then you can also allow themes to override your form if you want to.

Comment: Thanks webaware, When using load_template(), I needed to put the form phtml file in to the theme diectory. But i just wanted to keep the phtml sepearate in the same plugin folder, so I just used require_once() to include that file. Thanks for your help!